# The deja-dup-monitor allocates 112G of virtual memory - is it normal?

Tags: 18.04, deja-dup

I have clean installation of Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS with MATE DE.

In `htop` I see that `deja-dup-monitor` wants 112G of virtual memory.

[image: deja-dup-monitor and 112G of memory]

Is it normal?